# bootstrap scrollable div into body height 100%

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I want to make body fixed with 100% height and a main div inside the body scrollable and having some margin around. Something like this :

[image]

Comment: show me the code you have tried so far??

Comment: I found a solution using jquery; I get the body height onload and on resize minus 100px (for padding). Thank you anyway

Comment: use css `calc()` is easier than jquery! learn it to make your code cleaner.
if you use jquery, that piece of code must run onload and onresize, much harder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You really don't need Bootstrap for this!

In case of you can't run the snippet, this is the pen on CodePen: http://codepen.io/kranzy/pen/bwqWbo

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
.full {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: red;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.inside {
  position: relative;
  /* some bit of margins */
  top: 50px;
  left: 50px;
  /* calculate the width, if not, weird effect. */
  width: calc(100% - 50px * 2);
  height: calc(100% - 50px * 2);
  /* 50px * 2 because 50px is just enough for the .inside div's width and height not to fall out of screen. */
  /* make it like your image */
  background-color: blue;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="full">
  <div class="inside"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Would you like to add some text into inner block? The code snippet will be clearer when the scroll bar appear.

Comment: I think I shouldn't because you will have to delete the lorem ipsum text to use the code. But if it is important feel free to edit my answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="main" style="background-color:red; height:100vh; float:left; width:100%;>

    <div class="wrapper" style="width:1170px;margin:0 auto">
    <div class="main-text" style="float:left; width:100%; background-color:blue;">

</div>

<div>

</div>
```